# where can i find the detailed description just like “image/*” in android doc

Tags: java, android

What type can I set?
I want detailed description,thanks.

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
intent.setType("image/*");
Intent intent=new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");  
intent.setType("audio/*");
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html

Comment: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image